# How to download a web site with specific cookies set?

Tags: websites

I want to download a site with specific cookies set. I tried [SiteSucker](https://ricks-apps.com/osx/sitesucker/index.html) but found there are no options to set headers. So I could not set a cookie.

Are there other Mac tools or apps I can use?

Comment: I've added a rather general answer about how to use `curl` for this. If you need the answer to be more specifically tailored to the problem you are facing, please add details about how the cookies get created in the first place and how you identify their values.

Comment: `wget` can download an entire website; however, it is not a default utility in macOS and would need to be installed either compiled directly from source code or install via Homebrew.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `curl` in Terminal for this. Besides `man curl` there is a [tutorial](https://curl.haxx.se/docs/manual.html) available explaining the different usage scenarios. To set/use cookies you can use either

```
curl -b "sessionID=123456789" www.example.com
```

to set a cookie value directly, or use the `--dump-headers`, `-c` and `-b` options for more elaborate cases.

Comment: this command cannot download entire site, it just download one page

Comment: @TangMonk You can install `wget` via [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) which supports both cookies *and* recursive downloads.